# Proving solution of partial differential equation. Let $p: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a differentiable function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Prove that the equation $u_t = p(u)u_x ; t>0$ has a solution satisfying the functional relation $u=f(x+p(u)t)$ , where $f$ is a differentiable function. In particular, find such solution for the following equations:

(a) $u_t = ku_x$

(b) $u_t= uu_x$

(c) $u_t = u \sin (u)  u_x$

Comment: The title should be a summary of the question, not its first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

We have $u=f(x+p(u)t)=f(y)$ with $y=x+p(u)t$ therefore 
\begin{align}
u_t &= f_y  \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}= f_y\cdot p(u) \quad \text{ by chain rule}\\
u_x &= f_y \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = f_y
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
u_t  =p(u) u_x \Leftrightarrow f_y \cdot p(u) =  p(u) \cdot f_y
\end{align}
So $u=f(x+p(u)t)$ is a solution of the pde.

Comment: what do you mean by $f_y$ ?

Comment: ahh.., derivative respect to $y$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = f_y \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$
Sorry I was inconsistent